# Relative Layout in Xaml , cannot put View in the correct place

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have problem in Xamarin.Forms Relative Layout ,, ok i have 4 views 3 images and one label as photo  i attach with my question i want the 3rd image to be below the second image , and vertical size of second image is changing according to the size of label over the image2 how i can find the Y to image3 ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40eky.jpg)

the code in xaml

```
enter code here




<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="demo.AttnamePage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:demo.MarkupExtensions" >

    <ListView x:Name="AttNamea" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="AttNamea_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Image x:Name="Mimage" Source="{Binding image  }" Aspect="Fill"   
                      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}" 
                      RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0}"
                      RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0}"/>
                    <Image Source="{local:Embeddedimage ResourceId=Demo.Images.barM.jpg }"  Aspect="Fill"
                      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}" 
                      RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=Mimage,Property=Height,Factor=1}"
                      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=label1,Property=Height,Factor=1}"/>
                     <Label x:Name="label1" Text="{Binding attractionName}" TextColor="White" FontSize="16"  HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                      verticalOptions="Center"
                      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}" 
                      RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=Mimage,Property=Height,Factor=1}"/>
                    <Image Source="{local:Embeddedimage ResourceId= demo.Images.barD.jpg }"  Aspect="Fill"
                      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}" 
                      RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                           "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=label1,Property=Y,Constant=40}"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </ViewCell>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Why are you using a RelativeLayout?  From what you've described so far, a Grid (with single column) or Vertical StackLayout will do what you want.  If you do want to use RelativeLayout, though, you'll probably need to define the constraints on the last image in C#, as you have more flexibility in C# than XAML.

Comment: thank you for your reply i use Relative Layout because i want to put the Label Over the image , I will try to use C# as you say ,, yes i need to replay the code but let see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, the RelativeLayout constraint you need can't be expressed in XAML, but can be in C#.

However you can get the layout you want using a Grid. By assigning the Label and the barM.jpg Image to the same Row, they will be overlaid, as desired:

```
<ListView x:Name="AttNamea" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="AttNamea_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="Mimage" Source="{Binding image  }" Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="0"/>

                <Image Source="{local:Embeddedimage ResourceId=Demo.Images.barM.jpg }"  Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="1"/>

                <Label x:Name="label1" Text="{Binding attractionName}" TextColor="White" FontSize="16"  HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                  verticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>

                <Image Source="{local:Embeddedimage ResourceId= demo.Images.barD.jpg }" Aspect="Fill" Grid.Row="2"/>

                </Grid>

            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Xamarin.Forms performance guidance (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/performance/#optimizelayout) suggests avoiding RelativeLayout if possible due to the amount of work the CPU has to do.  Since this is for a ListView, that could mean a noticeable difference during scrolling.

Comment: Honestly i do not know how to thank you , its work , yesterday i try to use Grid but i have compiler error , so i do not try hard to find the error , now after i read your Code i find my mistake every things OK , from first i was thinking to use C# but i always like to make UI in side and code behind in another side  .. this is more easy to maintenance and more clean code ,, really appreciate for your support , with respect